# AWS Lambda error "Cannot find module 'mongodb'"

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I've successfully deployed my function to AWS.

When trying to invoke the function (`serverless invoke -f facebookAdInsert -l`), I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'mongodb'",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
        "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
        "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
        "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:222:18)",
        "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:20:30)",
        "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:234:16)",
        "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:20:30)",
        "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:303:16)",
        "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/src/facebookAdInsert.js:20:30)"
    ]
}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.268.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.17",
    "parse-mongo-url": "^1.1.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.33.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
}
```

Any ideas as to what the issue could be? Based on my research possible solutions were running `npm install` before deploying and moving all "devDependencies" to "dependencies" but those have not worked.

Comment: have you manage to solve it? Can you share your serverles.yml file?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the mongodb layer for AWS lambda

Open a terminal and type

1. mkdir nodejs
2. cd nodejs
3. npm init -y
4. npm install mongodb
5. zip the entire nodejs folder, making sure that if you unzip the folder you get the following structure

```
    nodejs
      +---node_modules
             +---------- (mongodb and other folders)
```

6. Upload this layer to AWS Lambda
7. Add the layer to your Lambda function

With this it should work without problems.

Regards

Comment: do you have to upload .zip file then every time you make some change ?